# Stuck while integrating facebook-connect with django

Tags: django, facebook

I was using https://github.com/ryanmark/django-facebookconnect for using facebook-connect with my django powered website . However , i'm stuck at various places . I'm unable to get my friends list , their information and lot of other stuffs .

Has anyone successfully implemented facebook-connect with that?
Or would you recommend another third party facebook-connect application?

Comment: 1. It says there `WARNING: THIS THING IS OBSOLETE - DON'T USE IT` and `Use this one instead: http://github.com/ryanmark/django_facebook_oauth`. 2. It always helps to post code.

Comment: Awesome . This works . Can you please tell me how to get data like friends lists and their information? I have the access token . I just don't know how to use it . Thanks for the information ... Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have one great solution . Thanks to Nitzan Tomer i have a working facebook application . 
http://github.com/ryanmark/django_facebook_oauth